# An array and a variable as parameters in subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
sub abc()
{

}

abc(@array, $a);
```

How do I access `@array` and `$a` in subroutine `abc()`?

I know about `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`, but I wasn't sure if I can use it for arrays.

Comment: I'm going to suggest my writeup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680147/perl-passing-2-or-more-arrays-to-a-subroutine/5681178#answer-5681178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers explained the two basic approaches. However, it is important to note that there is a big difference between the two: When you pass an array by reference, any changes you make to it *also change the original array*. Here is an example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

sub by_ref
{
    my $array_ref = $_[0];
    @$array_ref = (0, 0, 0);
    print "Array inside by_ref: @$array_ref\n";
}

sub by_val
{
    my @array_copy = @_;
    @array_copy = (0,0,0);
    print "Array inside by_val: @array_copy\n";
}

by_val(@array);

print "Original array after calling by_val: @array\n";

by_ref(\@array);

print "Original array after calling by_ref: @array\n";
```

If you do pass by reference, you need to keep this behavior in mind, making a copy of the referenced array if you don't want changes made in your sub to affect the original.

Comment: You can change without reference just as easily. Try: `sub change { $_[1] = 42 }; my @arr = (1, 2, 3); change(@arr); print $arr[1], "\n";`

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, yes, that is a good point.  However, I think the distinction between the two is still important.  Normal convention is to copy passed parameters from `@_` into lexical variables, but with pass-by-reference that doesn't stop you from modifying the original.

Comment: If I need the changes to reflect in my original array what will I have to do. If the answer is too big please post it as another answer...Thank you dan1111.

Comment: @Daanish, using pass-by-reference, as illustrated above in the sub `by_ref`, will change the original array.  Alternatively, you could alter `@_` directly as Oleg V. Volkov showed in his comment.

Answer (score 6):

You access a sub's arguments with the `@_` array. The first argument is `$_[0]`, the second - `$_[1]`, etc. In this particular case, your array will be unrolled to list of its elements, so `$_[0]` is `$array[0]`, `$_[1]` is `$array[1]` and then after all those elements, last element of `@_` will be the value of `$a`.

If you want to avoid unrolling that always happens when you use an array in a list context, use a reference to the array instead. References to arrays and hashes are created using `\`. So call your function like:

```
abc(\@array, $a);
```

After that, `$_[0]` will have reference to `@array` and `$_[1]` will be `$a`. To access array elements through reference, use `->` operator. `$_[0]->[2]` is same as `$array[2]`. Actually you can even drop `->` as long as it is between brackets, so `$_[0][2]` will work too. See more details on references in [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref).

Comment: Thank you @Oleg V. Volkov. Can you elaborate on the referencing of an array? I'll give it to you if you do that.

Comment: `I'll give it to you.` I see what you did there.

Answer (score 6):

You have two options:

1. Pass the scalar variable first (the dirty way)

   ```
   abc($a, @array);
   ```

   Then receive the parameters in subroutine as

   ```
   my ($a, @array) = @_;
   ```
2. Pass your array as reference by adding a backslash before the array variable (recommended)

   ```
   abc(\@array, $a);
   ```

   Then receive the parameters in subroutine as

   ```
   my ($array_ref, $a) = @_;
   ```

   And dereference the $array_ref

   ```
   my @array = @$array_ref;
   ```

More information about [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: The first way isn't dirty in my humble opinion. It has [different semantics](https://gist.github.com/3910729).

Comment: I agree it has different semantics. I say dirty because it will lead to something else if you have a third variable to pass other than scalar.

Comment: The first method is used by various built-in functions (`join` and `sprintf`, for example).  There is nothing wrong with it as long as it fits what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you pass the array reference instead of an array as mentioned by Oleg V. Volkov like

```
sub abc()
{
    my ( $array, $a ) = @_; #receiving the paramters
    my @arr = @{$array}; # dereferencing the array
}

abc(\@array,$a);
```

Comment: @Zaid, actually the prototype is a serious error.  This code won't run, because now `abc` does not accept any arguments.

Comment: dan1111 is right...I just faced this problem while running this code.