# Passing a two-dimensional array to sub routine perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, subroutine

I have this array:

```
print ("Grade\n");
        for (my $j=0; $j < $size; $j++){
            for (my $i=0; $i < $sizeCol; $i++){
                print("$newMatrizGrades[$j][$i] ");
            }
            print ("\n");
        }

newSubject ($name,@newArrayNames,@newMatrizGrades);
}
```

On the print, I can see the elements. But when i'm inside the routine. Acessing the array in this way $*[$sizeNewArrayName] , I get an address instead of the values. The @newArrayNames is a 1-dimensional array, which i can access the elements $*[1],$*[2],...,$*[$sizeNewArrayName], without futher problems. Someone can help me?

Comment: See this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680147/passing-two-or-more-arrays-to-a-perl-subroutine should help you ... you have to dereference the array

Comment: You can't pass arrays to subs. What you have is equivalent to `newSubject($name, $newArayNames[0], $newArayNames[1], ..., $newMatrizGrades[0], $newMatrizGrades[1], ...)` Pass references to the arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perl mashes subroutine arguments into one long list (and therefore can't identify the separate list/array variables), so in this case, you need to send in references to the arrays, and then dereference them within the sub when you go to use them:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

newSubject($name, \@newArrayNames, \@newMatrizGrades);

sub newSubject {
    my ($name, $names, $grades) = @_;

    for (@$names){
        # do something
    }

    print "$grades->[0][0]\n";
}
```